# soapUI 5.0 oracle connection jars

Tags: java, oracle, jar, soapui

I am using SoapUI 5.0.0 . I was trying to connect to oracle db through this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
// open connection
def mockService = mockRunner.mockService
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://" + mockService.getPropertyValue( "dbHost" ) +
mockService.getPropertyValue( "dbName" ),
mockService.getPropertyValue( "dbUsername" ),
mockService.getPropertyValue( "dbPassword" ), "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
log.info "Succesfully connected to database"
```

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

After some research found out that I need to copy some jars from `lib` to `\bin\ext`

but there are no such jars as  `msbase.jar, mssqlserver.jar, msutil.jar or ojdbc14.jar` in lib folder. What is the correct jar for soapui 5.0 to connect to an oracle db. Thank You. appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

List of drivers compatible with SoupUI (and links to download locations) is available on the project site: [JDBC Driver List](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/jdbc-driver-list.html).

And, by the way, fix your connection string - your value looks like connection to mysql. An Oracle example:

```
sql = Sql.newInstance(
   "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",
   "username",
   "password",
   "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" )
```

See [FAQ - GSQL](http://groovy.codehaus.org/FAQ+-+GSQL) to get more info.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've put `ojdbc6.jar` from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) for  11.2.0.3 oracle db into my `\bin\ext` and corrected the string like this `jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:1522:YY`  but I still get this error `No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@..`  what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @user1207289 No idea how to make it work in `SoapUI-5.0.0/bin/ext`. Place it under `SoapUI-5.0.0/lib` instead.

Comment: Thank you , it worked. actually the above said jar file and also this `orai18n.jar` needs to be put in the `lib` folder. I am using soapui 5.0 . In case anyone is looking. Please refer [here](http://forum.loadui.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=8674&p=24999&hilit=no+suitable+driver+found+for&sid=8445179728989be3eec1a2971b9bb693#p24999)